# Using random to pick a program from a given list of Strings

Tags: haskell, random

I'm trying to pick a programm at random from a given list and retrieve a random value (s) so it does complain when i try to run it

```
gp = do
 randomRIO (0, length programms - 1) >>= \s -> putStrLn(show(programms !!s  ++s))
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what is `programms`? - anyway `s` surely is no list so `++ s` is not what you want - you probably wanted `show (programms !! s) ++ show s` instead

Comment: BTW: it is not the worst idea to post the error you get ;)

Comment: programms  is a list of Strings i have given it some String values somewhere in my code
so i wanted to show (programms !! s) ++ show s like you saying

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
randomRIO (0, length programms - 1) >>= \s -> putStrLn(show(programms!!s) ++ show s))
```

or alternatively without the first `show` if `programms` is already a list of strings.